# Recording scripts - "page not found" because of single protocol?

Tags: testing, loadrunner

I have found a strange issue which I do not completely understand. When I run the LoadRunner with just a single protocol, the browser (when recording starts) is ran but says "page not found" (as if the proxy was not set).
How come? The protocols specify what traffic will be captured but I assumed in just does not record the ones not specified. But why the browser could not find the page in single protocol and could in multiple?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the single protocol mode (I assume web here) is somewhat erratic and does not work all the time. The workaround is to use the multiple protocol mode, but select only Web (HTTP/HTML). This works much better.

The actual reasons for why this is the case are unknown, but at least give it a try!

As for other issues:

Check that your PROXY settings are correct when you invoke IE for recording. Your issue sounds a little like a proxy issue, but please post more details if none of the above works.

Answer (score 0):

Over 90% of recording issues can be tracked to environment items, specifically do you have the right match up between version of LR and version/manufacturer of your browser **plus** are you signed in with the proper credentials **plus** do you have any conflicting software packages loaded, such as antivirus, which could be impacting the recordingf mechansim.

Where to start?

1. Makes sure you are signed in with Administrative credentials
2. Disable any antivirus running locally
3. Validate your browser manufacturer and version with the requirements for your version of LoadRunner